# angularjs SPA - MVC style layouts

Tags: javascript, angularjs, layout, ngroute

Ok, so I am quite new to AngularJS and on a very steep learning curve.

I am developing an AngularJS SPA and have got the basics down, I am using ngRoute for my routing and have a rudimentary application framework.

I have hit my next stumbling block and this may be my lack of knowledge of the AngularJS framework but I am looking to achieve something akin to the MVC layouts in my SPA application, what I am looking for is something like the following scenario:

Login.html - no layout, the layout will be defined in this page
Home.html - uses layout.tpl.html and the rest of the content is define in Home.html

... and so on, you get the general id, so for Homt.html i would be looking to do something like

```
<div layout="layout.tpl.html">
... rest of content
</div>
```

and layout.tpl.html would be

```
<div class="container">
  ..layout content for header, left nav, whatever is required
  <div class="content">
    <div layout-content></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As I said above I am using ngRoute so in my module I setup the route provider, I am hoping to achieve the equivalent of

```
@ {
Layout = "_Layout.cshtml"; // or Layout = null;
}
```

But in angularjs so any suggestion on how to achieve this would be greatly received

Comment: No there is no options, you can add external html by ng-include or write some directive that will add external html into your code snap by using angular module ngSanitize.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to detect when `ng-include` finished loading, depending on your need:

1) via onload attribute - for inline expressions. Ex:

```
<div ng-include="'template.html'" onload="loaded = true"></div>
```

2) via an event `$includeContentLoaded` that `ng-include` emits - for app-wide handling. Ex:

```
app.run(function($rootScope){
  $rootScope.$on("$includeContentLoaded", function(event, templateName){
     //...
  });
});
```

**OR**

Use directive to fix this

HTML

```
<div custom-include url="{{url}}"></div>
```

Directive

```
app.directive('customInclude', ['$http', '$compile', '$timeout', customInclude]);
    function customInclude($http, $compile, $timeout) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function link($scope, elem, attrs) {
                //if url is not empty
                if (attrs.url) {
                    $http({ method: 'GET', url: attrs.url, cache: true }).then(function (result) {
                        elem.append($compile(angular.element(result.data))($scope));
                        //after sometime we add width and height of modal
                        $timeout(function () {
                            //write your own code
                        }, 1, false);
                    });
                }
            }
        };
    }
```

**OR:**

```
<div ng-include src="template.html"></div>
```

Comment: I have updated my question with a bit more detail about what I want, I basically want to be able to specify a `Layout` in each routes `templateUrl` how is this possible with angular